# org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender stuck in starting up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, smtp

My application is stuck in starting up ,any help would be greatly appreciated. Things where working fine but suddenly nothing is working.

```
2021-05-15 08:03:37.599  INFO 9316 --- [  restartedMain] ingBootEmailThymeleafTemplateApplication : Started SpringBootEmailThymeleafTemplateApplication in 6.915 seconds (JVM running for 7.907)
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
```

application.property values

```
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.host=***
spring.mail.username=***
spring.mail.password=***
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the `spring.mail.host` property.

Comment: the values are present, i just didn't post it here, I have updated the complete list of properties removing the user credentials part

Comment: Show something like `***`, so we can see you have a value, but masked it for security reasons, as opposed to specifying a blank value. Might even be good to explicitly say that after the properties, as a footnote.